# Async Lambda Func<string>

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm a beginner with the async/await and I'm getting an error on my code that I'm not able to figure out how to fix it:

```
public static Func<string> GetTheID;

void Main()
{
    GetTheID = async () => await GetMyId(); //Error here!

    Console.WriteLine(GetTheID);
}

public async Task<string> GetMyId()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return "AAABBBB";
    });
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type
>   `'Func<string>'`. An async lambda expression may return `void`, `Task` or
>   `Task<T>`, none of which are convertible to `'Func<string>'`

Could you please help me how to fix this error without changing the signature of the `GetTheID` delegate (I means without changing its signature to `Func<Task<string>>`)?

Comment: Not possible. If you want to await something, it has to return a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with C# 7.1, you can actually have an [async `Main()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#async-main-return-values) function, which enables you to use `await` in the described situation:

```cs
static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
    return await AsyncConsoleWork();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the signature of the `GetTheID`, and there isn't any other way. So as the error suggest, you need to change the type of `GetTheID` to `Func<Task<string>>`, it has to return a `Task` or `Task<T>` in order to be able to await it:

```
public static Func<Task<string>> GetTheID;
```

Comment: Small correction: It has to return a `Task` or `Task<T>`, not a `void`, to be awaited.

Answer (score -2):

use this:

```
void Main()
{
    GetTheID = () => GetMyId().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine(GetTheID);
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error:
`'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found`

Comment: This doesn't return a string but the ToString of System.Func. You need to Invoke

Comment: And GetAwaiter is _This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code._

Comment: @Steve While you're correct that the docs say this, this is exactly what async internals use and there are also examples of this "boilerplate" code for invoking something async in a sync context, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#async-main-return-values